# How to write value from Website <textarea> in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I don't write into textarea in website.
My code is:

```
odoo.define('website_sale.cart', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    (function (window, document, undefined) {

        var add_comment = function (ele) {
            var store_order = $('#store_order').val();
            ajax.jsonRpc('/shop/customer_comment/', 'call', {
                'store_order': store_order 
            }).then(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                     var store_order1 = document.getElementById('store_order');
                     console.log('comment'+ store_order1);
                     store_order1.innerHTML = "store_order" ;
                }

            });
        };
        window.store_order = store_order1;

    })(window, document);

});
```

and xml is:

```
<textarea rows="3" id="store_order" class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Write a ..."/>
```

the console log is gives me "comment[object HTMLInputElement]".
My question is that:
How can i press button, put values in textarea ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use a textarea like this instead :

```
<textarea rows="3" id="store_order" class="form-control"placeholder="Write a ..."></textarea>
```

or try with

```
store_order1.value = "store_order" ;
```

instead of `store_order1.innerHTML = "store_order" ;`

Comment: I have another question, go to page in